# Date localization

Tags: internationalization, yii, date-formatting

Can anybody help me with date localization?
My code:

```
<?php echo date("j F", ($data->create_time)); ?>
```

And it returns:

> 1 January

I want to translate this output to Russian language:

> 1 Января

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii provides robust i18n functionality through classes such as [`CDateFormatter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter) and [`CLocale`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLocale). You can get an instance of these classes for your application's [current language](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#language-detail) with `Yii::app()->getDateFormatter()` and `Yii::app()->getLocale()`. Use these to format your date with a format string either taken straight from the current locale (good if it works for you) or by specifying a custom string:

```
$formatter = Yii::app()->getDateFormatter();

$format = Yii::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat('medium'); // use built-in
$format = 'd MMMM'; // or use custom
echo $formatter->format($format, $data->create_time);
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but where I should define that i want Russian format?

Comment: @Nick_NY: From your [application configuration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-configuration): `'languge' => 'ru'`.

Comment: that uses us by default. how can it automatically select uk or us depending on a variable/something

Answer (score 1):

i didn't run this code but looks what you are looking for.

http://kr2.php.net/strftime

Udachi^^